# I want to remove 1 color channel from a tif in zcyx and save it in zyx

Tags: python, tiff, channel, zstack

I though it would be as simple as picking 1 color and keeping the rest of the axis the same.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import tifffile as tif
import os

def SplitChannel(ImName):
    TifIm = tif.imread(ImName)
    return TifIm[:,1,:,:] #for some reason this makes the tiff read cyx vs zyx

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title = "Select the directory containing Tif files")
    ImageNames = os.listdir(Folder)
    SaveFolder = Folder + " Split Red Channel2" 
    os.mkdir(SaveFolder)
    os.chdir(Folder)
    for Image in ImageNames:
        if Image.split(".")[-1] == "tif":
            print("here")
            SplitRed = SplitChannel(Image)
            os.chdir("...")
            os.chdir(SaveFolder)
            tif.imwrite(Image + "_Red.ome.tif",SplitRed,imagej= True)
            os.chdir("...")
            os.chdir(Folder)
```

But this gives me a tif in cyx vs zyx.
How can I make sure the resulting tif knows I removed a color channel, and not z

Comment: Please put your `import` statements back in so we know what packages you are using, so it is a proper [mcve].

Comment: Either keep the channel axis `TifIm[:,1:2,:,:]` or specify the axes in `imwrite(..., metadata={'axes': 'ZYX'}`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update:  Thank you to cgohlke.  Specifying the axes in the metadata has done the trick.

```py
tif.imwrite(Image + "_Red.ome.tif",SplitRed,imagej= True,metadata= {'axes': 'ZYX'})
```

Thank you everyone and sorry for being vague